# How to manage branches?

Tags: version-control, mercurial

I am using Mercurial as my source control for my app. So far, it's been simple to manage the branch: I commit my changes and add a tag when I publish an update. That's it.

For the last week, I've been working on a "Holiday" version of my app. The code is pretty much the same, the only thing that changes are pictures, sounds, etc. However, the way I've been doing this isn't going to work well long term. Once the holidays are over, I'll have to rollback to a previous commit and continue from there.

Here's my question: Should I be creating a branch for the holiday edition of my app? If so, is it too late? Let's say that I continue to improve my non-holiday edition of my app in 2014 and want to publish a new version of the holiday one in 2014, how to I integrate between branches?

Thanks!

Comment: If you do decide to move them to a named branch. As long as your changes haven't left your repo ( haven't been pushed or pulled ), you can use rebase to move the holiday commits to a named branch.

Comment: @Kindread - How would I do that?

Comment: I've followed http://blog.dowski.com/2010/07/09/rebasing-to-a-new-branch-with-mercurial/ before and it worked like a charm. I skipped step 1 because I like to live dangerously ;)

Answer (score 0):

First of all its not late, and this is best scenario where you can use Branching strategy.

1. Stable trunk(branch) strategy
2. Unstable trunk(branch) strategy

First one is good for your scenario, where you can create multiple branches and re-integrate all branches with one branch.

so create holiday branch(s) and re-integrate branch with Production(active) branch.

to find out more google it for both terms

Answer (score 0):

I bet you'd be interested in a systematic branching model/strategy. The best and most general model that I know is the [flow](https://bitbucket.org/yujiewu/hgflow/wiki/Home) extension for hg. I have been used it for several years, and it's one of the best things of Mercurial IMO. I won't be able to summarize how the model works in a short post, I encourage you to read its WIKI.